# Xcode 8 beta 5 : The operation couldn't be completed

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, mach, xcode8-beta5

I'm working on **Xcode 8 beta 5.** While running app on iPhone SE simulator I'm getting an error that `The operation couldn't be completed. (Mach error - 308 - (pic/mig) server died).`

[image: Screenshot 1]

I tried clean build, restart Xcode but didn't worked.

Any fix?

Comment: Xcode 8 GM is out. Do not use an outdated beta any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me on Xcode 8 GM as well. The issue was the Simulator presenting a spinner endlessly, independently of the model chosen (6, 6S, 7, SE). When it eventually times out I get the message mentioned, and get it as well when I force quit the Simulator. What solved it for me: I was running Xcode 8 GM from my /Downloads folder, so I archived and moved Xcode 7 away from /Applications, and replaced it by Xcode 8 GM. Voilà.

What failed:
- project clean + clean build folder
- Simulator "reset contents and settings"
though that never hurts.

Hope it helps someone.